# Find number of people it takes to reach one person from another

Tags: algorithm, graph

Here's the question set-up: You pick a random person(A) on a social network, say, Facebook and pick another random person(B) on Facebook. Assuming that you have access to each person's friend list, how can you find the number of people it will take to reach B from A.
For ex: 
A is friends with C, V, T, Y, Z
C is friends with V, T, A, L
V is friends with C, A, Q, W
T is friends with C, A, Q, B 
Y and Z also have some set of friends.
Ans for this would be one because A->T->B

What's an efficient way to solve this question?

Comment: Depends on your data representation. In general, you want to find the shortest path from A to B.

Comment: Right, except, I think it gets tedious to go through lists over lists until you find a link.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra Algorithm.
You just need to represent the relationship as an graph.

Comment: BFS would be simpler and faster.

Comment: Probably even bidirectional BFS because the branching factor is usually very high in friend graphs.